# DateValue failure

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've a strange problem with the MS Access VBA `DateValue` function : it fails with a type mismatch error when I pass to it the value "4 May 2012".

I think is due the internal date format, but I don't known how to change at code level that format!

At the moment my solution is:

```
 Public Function DateToStr(Value)

   Dim Parts As Variant   Parts = Split(Value, " ")
      Dim Month As String
      Select Case Parts(1)
     Case "Jan"
         Month = "Gen"
     Case "May"
         Month = "Mag"
     Case "Jun"
         Month = "Giu"
    Case "Jul"
         Month = "Lug"
     Case "Aug"
         Month = "Ago"
     Case "Sep"
         Month = "Set"
     Case "Oct"
         Month = "Ott"
     Case "Dec"
         Month = "Dic"
     Case Else
         Month = Parts(1)   End Select
      DateToStr = CDate(Parts(0) & "/" & Month & "/" & Parts(2))

 End Function
```

Do you have any idea?!?

**PS:** my environment is italian.

Comment: Remove the `CDate` function

Answer (score 0):

In datevalue function

```
DateValue ("May 4, 2012")
```

And to make "May 4, 2012" ...

```
Function DateStr(sDS As String) 
'-- format input (sDS) -> dd-mmm-yyyy - ex. "04-Mag-2012" or "04 Mag 2012"

    Dim sMonth As String = ""

    Select Case Mid(sDS, 4, 3)
        Case "Gen" : sMonth = "January"
        ....
        ....
        Case "Dic" : sMonth = "December"
    End Select
    DateStr = sMonth & " " & Left(sDS, 2) & ", " & Right(sDS, 4)

End Function
```